# Error in implementing hmsonline Cassandra-Trigger

Tags: triggers, cassandra

Was trying to implement the triggers in Cassandra.

Have been trying to use the available Cassandra help: https://github.com/hmsonline/cassandra-triggers
Porting it on the latest version 1.2.3, and following the [GettingStarted](https://github.com/hmsonline/cassandra-triggers/wiki/GettingStarted/) instruction.

when i tried to set the value for the trigger, inserting the data to fire the log, and checked the logs, following is the error which i received

> java.lang.AssertionError
>
> > > ```
> > >    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftSessionManager.currentSession(ThriftSessionManager.java:51)
> > >    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.state(CassandraServer.java:88)
> > >    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.validateLogin(CassandraServer.java:881)
> > >    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.set_keyspace(CassandraServer.java:1492)
> > >    at com.hmsonline.cassandra.triggers.dao.CassandraStore.getConnection(CassandraStore.java:42)
> > >    at com.hmsonline.cassandra.triggers.dao.ConfigurationStore.getConfiguration(ConfigurationStore.java:76)
> > >    at com.hmsonline.cassandra.triggers.dao.ConfigurationStore.isCommitLogEnabled(ConfigurationStore.java:44)
> > >    at com.hmsonline.cassandra.triggers.TriggerTask.run(TriggerTask.java:47)
> > >    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
> > > ```

But we test it works fine at older version(ex: 1.1.2)

So is this a configuration problem, or the Thrift API implementation has been changed?

thanks